# Magento Collection load for sales order with custom fields

Tags: magento-1.4

I am new to magento. I have added two text fileds(custom options) for products in magento admin panel.
When the customer purchasing products these two text fields are required. I need to load the collection for sales order to get this two fields.

Customer fields namely like:
1) domain name 2) activation code

Can any one give me guidance? How to get this text fields from magento sales order?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below collection will get your products custom fields from sales order 
I have tried my self and got the final result.

Note : These products custom fields values entered by the customer in the product details page.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
$orderItems->addFieldToFilter('product_options',array('like'=>'%'.$domain_name.'%'));
$data = $orderItems->getData();
```